# can a method have and input/output of different variables

Tags: java, methods, input

the method is:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Color inputColor = new Color();

Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 770);

    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++) 
        {
            if (image.getRGB(x, y) == inputColor.getRGB()) 
            {
            robot.mouseMove(x, y);
            break;
            }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

i want to call that method with a value for Color have it search the screenshot for that color and return with the (x, y) values for the pixel if it is found can that happen or can a method have only one input and the output has to be the same?

Comment: Please put the method signature in your code example and give examples of how you would like to call it and what you would like to use the return values for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Point methodName(Color color) {
    Point p = new Point();
    // logic for finding point
    return p; // or perhaps return null if color not found
}
```

You could also just return a two-element `int[]` instead of a point.

Comment: ok i did that but im getting 2 errors:                                    java21 ; expected that's pointing at the ( right after Name             java21 ; expected pointing tot he ) right after color

Comment: @user1179522 Did you import `java.awt.Point` and `java.awt.Color`?

Comment: @user1179522 - It sounds like you might have unbalanced braces or some other syntax problem earlier in the file. I suggest that you ask a new question and paste (don't type) in your code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Method input and output could be different, but it can't return more than one type(or)value, either x or y.  If you want to return both x,y. You may need to return as array (or) You can have a POJO class something like below, set x,y to instance of that class and return.

```
Dimension
{
int x;
int y;

setter..
getter..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) with the x and y values or use an `int` array if that would be fine.